# Why is the context item 'copy' not showing up in the context menu as described in the ag-grid documentation?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, react-scripts

I have a simple ag-grid setup...

```
const getContextDefault = ()=>([
    {
      name: "Do Something",
      action: ()=>({})
    },
    "copy"
]);
<AgGridReact
    ...
    modules={[MenuModule]}
    getContextMenuItems={getContextDefault}
    rowData={data.rows}/>
```

This is per the docs found on the [ag-grid site](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-context-menu/). In the example it declares copy just as I have here, however, when I try to run I see the `do something` item but not the copy one.

Why is copy not showing up?

## Update

Confirmed that it is using latest version. Application is ran using react-scripts style.

Comment: could you re-produce your issue in either Plunker or StackBlitz?

Comment: I haven't tried yet but I can, I will also check the version as where I am getting it from proxies the version. I will update when I have time to add the Plunker. Also this is using react-scripts to run the application

Comment: Have you imported `ag-grid-enterprise` library?

Comment: yeah, I am pretty sure right click wouldn't even work if I hadn't but yes I confirmed this.

Comment: here is a [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/IMrO9aVlZL20jlIZ). please edit this plunkr to reproduce your issue.